# Flatten nested pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering how to flatten the nested pandas dataframe as demonstrated in the picture attached. [image]

The nested attribute is given by 'data' field. In short: I have a list of participants (denoted by 'participant_id') and they submitted responses ('data') at different times. I need to create the wide dataframe, where for each participant at each time stamp there is a row of records of their data ('q1', 'q2',...,'summary')

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please dont use png for data or table.

Comment: @Merlin, thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Can you fix the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df.data.apply(pd.Series), df.drop('data', axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: But the columns names are 0 ,1 and etc. and 0 wil have {"q1": "me"}, Instead can we get column name as "q1" and that value as "me" ?
@piRSquared